# How can i write this complex integrals in python? it contains functions of functions

Tags: python, function, limit, integral, quad

I am trying to write some integrals that contain functions of functions in python:

[image]

below is the code in python. i decided to break the problem into parts and integrate separately to simplify things. it returns error:

> m2=quad(lambda h:fh(h), 0, lambda x:S-x)[0]
> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'

i think probably because x, h, z and w are functions and not integer values.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad, dblquad, tplquad,nquad

#INPUT
a2=18
b2=5
a1=3
b1=2.5
p=1
l=0.5
ci=0.05
cr=1
cf=10
S=5
T=10
mi=0.1 #Rate of opportunity

Cost=lenght=0

def objective(S,T):
    def f01(x):#weibull density (strong component)
        return (b1/a1**b1)*(x**(b1-1))*np.exp(-(x/a1)**b1)
    def f02(x): #weibull density (weak component)
        return (b2/a2**b2)*(x**(b2-1))*np.exp(-(x/a2)**b2)
    #DEFECT
    def fx(x):
        return p*f01(x)+(1-p)*f02(x)
    #DELAY TIME
    def fh(h):#exponential density
        return l*np.exp(-l*h)
    def Fh(h):#cumulative exponential
        return 1-np.exp(-l*h)
    #DEMAND
    def fz(z):#exponential density
        return l*np.exp(-l*z)
    def Fz(z):#cumulative exponential
        return 1-np.exp(-l*z)
    #OPPORTUNIY
    def fw(w):#exponential density
        return l*np.exp(-l*w)
    def Fw(w):#cumulative exponential
        return 1-np.exp(-l*w)
    
    
    m1=quad(lambda x:fx(x), 0,S)[0] 
    m2=quad(lambda h:fh(h), 0, lambda x:S-x)[0]
    m3=1-quad(lambda z:fz(z), lambda x,h: x+h,T)[0]
    m4=1-quad(lambda w:mi*np.exp(-mi*(w-S))*fw(w), S,T) [0]
    P1=m1*m2*m3*m4
       
    
    return  P1

print(objective(S,T))
```

when i isolate m2 and m3, it didnt give an error.

is there is a way to write using 'nquad' and one line of code?

Comment: Is it possible to split the integrand into real and imaginary components and write the integrals separately or is the integrating domain also in the complex space?

Comment: it appears as though you are comparing a memory address `function` to an `int`. You should get the value of the function.